# How to automatically create a database when building a Spring-Boot application with Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot project with JPA. I have created a PostgreSQL database and a database-admin on my local machine (and also made some .sql files to create tables and fill in some test data). I specified it in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/messenger
spring.datasource.username=messenger_admin
spring.datasource.password=yEwXUcaNf8cp2RRD

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath*:database/db_create_tables.sql
spring.sql.init.data-locations=classpath*:database/db_fill.sql
```

It works fine, but when I try to build my project on another machine, I have to create a database with user manually or it just won't start. My question is - **how can I create a database and a user with permissions to it (if not already exists) when somebody builds my project?**

I tried to do it in my terminal and ended up with these commands:

```
sudo su postgres
(my password)
(postgres password)
psql
create database messenger
create user messenger_admin with encrypted password 'yEwXUcaNf8cp2RRD'
grant all privileges on database messenger to messenger_admin
```

But I can't made a script out of it, and don't know how to properly run it when building my project - should it be done with Maven or Spring-Boot? Moreover, I don't know if making such a script is a good solution at all. This is my first pet-project and I really want to understand some common practices.

P.S.
I don't want to use Docker at this point, just want to make it possible to run my application on different devices as it is.

Comment: You won't be able to create _the database_, meaning the container (and I strongly recommend using Flyway instead of scattered `.sql` files). If you need Postgres, then either you'll have to preconfigure the database, or you use Docker to ship it.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thanks, I understand that Docker is the best solution, but is there an opportunity to just somehow simplify / automate the process of creating a database for other developers working on my project?

Comment: As much as I personally think Docker is overused and oversold... this really is the precise case for it. Versioning, installed extensions, and so on are notoriously easy to get out of sync on different developers' machines. Docker _is_ the easy way to ensure a consistent configuration. (If you're absolutely set against Docker, you could wrap those statements up into a shell script.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- In that way I believe shall script is what I want, but I actually don't know how to make such a script, as I have to use psql terminal.

Comment: You can pipe commands (e.g., a here-document) to `psql`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Thank you a lot! I found out how to make a script with here-doc and it works as I wanted. I posted it as a solution to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a help of [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic) I came up making a shell script that will create a database and a user I want. This script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

psql << EOF
create database messenger;
create user messenger_admin with encrypted password 'yEwXUcaNf8cp2RRD';
grant all privileges on database messenger to messenger_admin;
EOF
```

It must be run by a user with permissions in PostgreSQL to create databases and manage user roles.

Answer (score -2):

In any case if you run your properties file on another system you will have to atleast create a schema, you can use "**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update**", to automatically initiate the tables. Although spring provides the feature to Initialize a Database via script and above property, it somehow does not work in the case if the system is changed(Tried it many times). Rest you can check it out here on Spring's official '**How To**' page:-- **https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization**

Comment: Thank you, but creating schema is actually not what I want. I want to create a database itself, and i cannot make it in properties because my Spring-Boot app won't launch without database at all.